# dynamic menu in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, menu

Im trying to create dynamic menu. Basically,I have two tables :Category and pages.Not sure how should I do this but following is something I have tried

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{url('/',null)}}" class="pull-left">Consulate</a>
        </div>
    <div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="{{url('/',null)}}">Home</a></li>
        @foreach($categories as $category )
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a  class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{$category->title}}<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            @foreach($pages as $page)
                <li><a href="{{action('publicpagecontroller@show',[$page->id])}}">{{$page->title}}</a></li>
            @endforeach
            </ul>
        </li>
        @endforeach
```

With above code, I got the same drop down menus in all the categories.I require dropdown only if the category have pages.
[example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQOBr.jpg)
[example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVEOz.jpg)

My models looks like following:
**Pages model**

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Pages extends Model
{
    protected $fillable=[
        'title',
        'details',
        'image',
        'category_id',
    ];

    //A page has a category

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Categories');
    }
}
```

**categories model**

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Categories extends Model
{
    protected $fillable=[
        'title',
        'details',
    ];
    public function pages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Pages');
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your database structure and what are you passing through for the categories and pages values from your controller. Your current code dosen't seem to show any relationship between the two.

Comment: @user3810794 you can delete that comment if its not relevant. You can also update your original question with any additional information needed. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could store your categories in a database table called categories (id, name, url). You could then also have another table called pages (id, name, url, category_id).

Create a Category and Page model.

Define a one-to-many relationship (one category-to-many pages).

You could then do:

```
@foreach( $categories as $category )
  <!-- display your category html -->

  @foreach( $category->pages as $page )
    <!-- display your page html -->
  @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Have a look at one-to-many relaitonships in Laravel: [Eloquent: Relationships - one-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Comment: Hi my database is similar as you have stated. I get following error after doing the loop 
"Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ....."

Comment: I noticed few mistakes and corrected them now im getting this error:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pages.categories_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `pages` where `pages`.`categories_id` = 4 and `pages`.`categories_id` is not null)

Comment: Hmm is your column called `categories_id` or `category_id`?  Could you post your code for the pages migration?

Comment: `$table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('title');
           
            $table->text('details');
            $table->boolean('is_published');
            $table->timestamps();
            
            $table->foreign('category_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('categories')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
`
I have category_id in my migration.

Comment: @user3810794 add `protected $table = 'categories';` to your categories model.